# Copying files in tomcat war extract directory using Dockerfile removes existing files

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, openshift, dockerfile

**What we know:**

When the war file is copied in the /opt/tomcat/webapps/ folder, tomcat extracts it and creates a folder in which all files from war are present. Let's say I am copying xyz.war file, so a new folder xyz will be created under /opt/tomcat/webapps/ path.

**What we want to achieve, but what's happening:**

We are using Docker and Openshift for the container creation on Linux server. We have created a Dockerfile, using which the xyz.war gets copied in /opt/tomcat/webapps folder. This works fine. Also, the war gets extracted and the xyz folder gets created correctly.

However, now we want to copy some additional configuration files in different locations inside /opt/tomcat/webapps/xyz folder. For eg. some files will go to /opt/tomcat/webapps/xyz path, some will go to /opt/tomcat/webapps/xyz/WEB-INF path, and some will go to /opt/tomcat/webapps/xyz/WEB-INF/classes path.

In Dockerfile, we are using the ['ADD' command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add) to copy the configuration files from source location to above destination locations. When we do this, the files do get copied correctly. However, whatever files were originally present in the /opt/tomcat/webapps/xyz folder, i.e. the extraction of xyz.war file, all those files are deleted immediately and automatically.

**Observations:**

If I use the ADD command to copy the files in some other folder, eg. opt/tomcat/conf, then the existing files do not get deleted. Only if I copy the files in the war's extract/output folder /opt/tomcat/webapps/xyz, then the existing files get deleted.

Hence, I believe the ADD command works as expected, but there is something in tomcat which is probably recognizing the change in web-application folder xyz and resetting everything (and just keeps latest copied files in it).

**What we have tried:**

We have tried to different sequences:

1. First copy war file, so that xyz folder gets created first. Then copy additional config files inside xyz folder.
2. First copy additional config files, and then copy the war file.

However, in both options above, only the additional config files remain, and the war's extracted files are deleted.

**Question:**

Any ideas if this has been observed by anyone under any circumstances (regardless of whether it was with Dockerfile/Openshift or not)? Any configurations of tomcat could do this automatically? How to prevent it from happening?

Note: I cannot club the required configuration files inside the 'xyz.war', because they would vary for different environments, whereas the xyz.war is a generic package. Hence, after war deployment, I have to copy few required configuration files manually in xyz folder.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I also had a similar scenario. Whenever you copy into the extracted folder using the dockerfile, rest of the content will get cleared off of the extracted folder and only the copied content was left. So, instead of keeping my war file inside the webapps, I moved it to the tmp folder and extracted it right into the webapps directory. This way if you copy anything inside the extracted directory, Tomcat will not try to compare it with the war file content and hence wont reset anything but copy that particular file.